# Computing Conditional Probability and Summing out Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistical-inference, bayes-theorem

Given random variables X, Y, and Z, each of which with domain {-1, 1}, compute $P(A=1|B=1 \cap C=1)$ given that the following are true:

- $P(X=1)=0.55$
- $P(Y=1|X=1)=0.66$
- $P(Y=1|X=-1)=0.2$
- $P(Z=1|X=1)=0.94$
- $P(Z=1|X=-1)=0.12$
- Z and Y are conditionally independent given X.

How do you compute this? I assume I'm supposed to use the chain rule, but:

$$P(X=1|Y=1 \cap Z=1)=\frac{P(X=1\cap Y=1\cap Z=1)}{P(Y=1 \cap Z=1)}$$

doesn't really help me much since I don't know the probability of any of these intersections.

Comment: Well, from the last four bullets you can easily obtain $P(X=1 \cap Y=1), P(X=-1 \cap Y=1), P(X=1 \cap Z=1), P(X=-1 \cap Z=1)$, but I think you're right that there's still insufficient info.  Basically you know perfectly how $X,Y$ overlap and how $X,Z$ overlap, but you don't know how $Y,Z$ overlap.  Are you sure you have listed all the info?

Comment: @jippyjoe4 Do you need additional explanations?

Answer (score 1):

After the original post was edited, there appears additional information:
$$
\mathbb P(Y=1,Z=1\mid X=1)=\mathbb P(Y=1\mid X=1)\cdot \mathbb P(Z=1\mid X=1)=0.94\cdot 0.66
$$
and 
$$
\mathbb P(Y=1,Z=1\mid X=-1)=\mathbb P(Y=1\mid X=-1)\cdot \mathbb P(Z=1\mid X=-1)=0.12\cdot 0.2
$$

From the first equality you can find $\mathbb (X=1,Y=1,Z=1)$.

To find $\mathbb P(Y=1, Z=1)$ find first $\mathbb (X=-1,Y=1,Z=1)$ from the second equality above and add 
$$
\mathbb P(Y=1, Z=1) = \mathbb P(X=-1,Y=1, Z=1)+\mathbb P(X=1,Y=1, Z=1).
$$